# Before and After trigger on the same event? Fill a child table PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, triggers, partitioning, return-type

**Situation**

I have a database in PostgreSQL 9.5 used to store object locations by time.

I have a main table named "position" with the columns (only relevant):

- `position_id`
- `position_timestamp`
- `object_id`

It is partitioned into 100 child tables on object_id with the condition:

```
CREATE TABLE position_object_id_00
( CHECK object_id%100 = 0 ) 
INHERITS ( position );
```

And so on for the others children. I partitioned with a modulus relation to distribute equally the objects.
Each child is indexed on `position_id and object_id` (two different indexes).

The trigger to redirect inserts on children is:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER insert_position_trigger
     BEFORE INSERT ON position
     FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_position();
```

And the procedure `insert_position()` looks for the right child table to insert the data, inserts it and then return the NEW object:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_position() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $insert_position$
  DECLARE

  BEGIN
    --Look for child table
    [...]
    --Insert data in right child table
    [...]

    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$insert_position$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have a summary table `object_last_known_position` with the same columns that is updated with the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_object_last_known_position 
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON position 
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_object_last_known_position();
```

The procedure `update_object_last_known_position()` basically checks if the `position_timestamp` is more recent, then delete the older entry and create a new entry with the data passed on the INSERT or UPDATE query (NEW).

**Issue**

So these two triggers react to the same event: insert on position, one is before, the other is after
Returning new for `insert_position()` allows me to use NEW in the trigger `update_object_last_known_position()`, and this is absolutely necessary. But doing that, it also insert the data on the master table position. So my data is now duplicated.

I tried to put the two triggers before, they both execute when I insert data if I let it like that, but if I remove the "return new" from the procedure `insert_position()`, `update_object_last_known_position()` is not executed.

I am stuck with this issue and I didn't find a way to execute both of these triggers without filling the master table position when I insert data.

So if you have any ideas, I will really appreciate :)

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT**

**Solution**

Thanks to the answer

I "merged" my two triggers: `insert_position()` now calls `update_object_last_known_position` directly. For that, I modified `update_object_last_known_position` to a stored procedure with a parameter. The parameter is the id of the position `insert_position()` just created, so I am able to find it and retrieve information.
(Calling `update_object_last_known_position` inside the other trigger means we cannot use `NEW` anymore)
And obviously return type for `insert_position()` is now `NULL`, and everything works fine :)

Comment: It would help to have more complete code but it sounds like you are inserting the new row in `update_object_last_known_position()` as well as it being inserted (in order to fire the trigger).  Could you just *not* insert the row in `update_object_last_known_position()`

Comment: The row inserted in the master table is not due to `update_object_last_known_position()` but to `insert_position()`. As it is a before trigger returning NEW, it doesn't "stop" the INSERT, I think.
And I need to insert a row in `object_last_known_position`, this is part of the design: I need to store the last position to have better performances when requesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to:

1. Stop the insert, and replace it with an insert into another table (determined by the trigger)
2. Update a summary table (`delete`/`insert`) to point to the new row.

Your problem is that 1 stops 2 from happening?  That's logical because you've stopped the insert so you've stopped any processing on the insert as well.

So to solve this you have a couple of options (options 1 and 2 are similar)

1. Call `update_object_last_known_position()` from `insert_position()` and only have one trigger
2. Create a wrapper method for both `insert_position()` and `update_object_last_known_position()` and have only one trigger.
3. Put the trigger for `update_object_last_known_position()` on all of the tables that `insert_position()` might insert into.