# Partition table with modulus, how to Index? PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing, partitioning, modulus

**Situation**

I have a database in PostgreSQL 9.5 used to store object locations by time.

I have a main table named "position" with the columns (only relevant):

- position_id
- position_timestamp
- object_id

It is partitioned into 100 child tables on object_id with the condition:

```
CREATE TABLE position_object_id_00
( CHECK object_id%100 = 0 ) 
INHERITS ( position );
```

And so on for the others children. I partitioned with a modulus relation to distribute equally the objects. 
Each child is indexed on position_id and object_id (two different indexes).

**Issue**

When I look for an object by it's ID, Postgres runs an Index Scan on each child table:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * 
FROM position
WHERE object_id = 3

"Append  (cost=0.43..35925.81 rows=51119 width=97) (actual time=0.109..46.362 rows=52418 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using position_object_id_position_timestamp_idx on position  (cost=0.43..34742.00 rows=24811 width=97) (actual time=0.108..15.367 rows=26209 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (object_id = 3)"
"  ->  Index Scan using position_object_id_00_object_id_idx on position_object_id_00  (cost=0.29..4.30 rows=1 width=97) (actual time=0.102..0.102 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (object_id = 3)"
"  ->  Index Scan using position_object_id_01_object_id_idx on position_object_id_01  (cost=0.29..4.30 rows=1 width=97) (actual time=0.065..0.065 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (object_id = 3)"
"  ->  Index Scan using position_object_id_02_object_id_idx on position_object_id_02  (cost=0.29..4.30 rows=1 width=97) (actual time=0.069..0.069 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (object_id = 3)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on position_object_id_03  (cost=0.00..757.61 rows=26209 width=97) (actual time=0.030..5.337 rows=26209 loops=1)"
"        Filter: (object_id = 3)"
"  ->  Index Scan using position_object_id_04_object_id_idx on position_object_id_04  (cost=0.29..4.30 rows=1 width=97) (actual time=0.067..0.067 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (object_id = 3)"

[...]
```

Except from the fact that there is data in my master table (first line) (see topic about that [Before and After trigger on the same event? Fill a child table PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141578/before-and-after-trigger-on-the-same-event-fill-a-child-table-postgresql)), Postgres doesn't "recognize" the check condition for the partition and look for the ID on each child table, while there is only the corresponding id in the table position_object_id_03.

Is there a particular way of indexing such that it directly knows on which table to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres cannot automatically apply the knowledge that `object_id = 3` to a check constraint, decide that `3 % 100 = 3` and pick corresponding partition. The only way to hint postgres which partition to pick is to explicitly use an expression from the check constraint in a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM position WHERE object_id = 3 AND object_id % 100 = 3;
```

Btw, we're developing an opensource extension for partitioning ([pg_pathman](https://github.com/postgrespro/pg_pathman)), which has built-in support for hash partitioning and it automatically understands that `object_id = 3` corresponds to a certain partition. Please check it out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also though of having a field "object_partition" which will store `object_id % 100`, so that we can query on `object_id = sth AND object_partition = sth%100`. This is quite similar :)